# PHPExcel doesn't read data if first cell is empty

Tags: php, phpexcel

Hi I recived Excel like this

```
date | hour | visit
X1   | Y1   | Z1
X2   | Y2   | Z2
X3   | Y3   | Z3
X4   | Y4   | Z4
     | Y5   | Z5
X6   | Y6   | Z6
```

For some reason X5 is missing which is OK for further use... but the problem is that PHPExcel Reader 1.7.6, 2011-02-27 skips that row automatically.

So if I just do that:

```
$objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($fileName);
$rowIterator = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getRowIterator();
print_r($rowIterator);
```

I will receive data like this:

```
date | hour | visit
X1   | Y1   | Z1
X2   | Y2   | Z2
X3   | Y3   | Z3
X4   | Y4   | Z4
X6   | Y6   | Z6
```

Any idea?

Comment: Besides suggesting that you update your version of PHPExcel to the most recent 1.7.8 version (1.7.6 is two years old now)?

Comment: But can you show your real code, because that's not the output I would expect to see from dumping the $rowIterator which is a PHP object, not a neatly formatted grid of data

Comment: Hi, did the update ... nothing happens ... I can post the whole array ... but the value is hidden - that is all...

Comment: It's your actual code I want to see... settings for the iterators (e.g. setIterateOnlyExistingCells(FALSE) for the cellIterator), and the code you're using to dump the cell values

Comment: Or consider using to Worksheet's toArray() method as it's actually faster than using the iterators

Comment: Great! Thanks for suggest... problem solved now ... If you put it in an answer I can confirm it...

Comment: Was it the toArray() method you used to solve the problem? or the setIterateOnlyExistingCells(FALSE)?

Comment: toArray() but it is strange ... it only occurs while reading one file ... other hundreds are OK ...